# PHP include and paths

Tags: php

I'm creating a website for school and I have a problem at including files with php.

So I've following structure:

- index.php
- include/

  - head.php
- style/

  - style.css
- sites/

  - contact.php

Now I have linked my CSS File in the header.php 
And the header.php is included in the index.php and in the contact.php,

The code of the header.php is:

```
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The code of the index.php is:

```
include 'include/head.php';
```

And the code of the contact.php is:

```
include '../include/head.php';
```

But the server can't find the css file, when I open the contact.php

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your path in relation to the root folder **or** the relative file location

So you need to do following changes

For root (absolute) path:

```
<link href="/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

or for relative path:

```
<link href="../style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `link` element to this:

```
<link href="/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The starting slash makes it an absolute path, which points to the root of your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to `style/style.css` means get this path `style/style.css` from current working directory where as `/style/style.css` means path from `document_root` which will work perfectly fine in all cases if you use this in any file.

**Change this to:**

```
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**This:**

```
<link href="/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```